# What is the implicit command in "thing.o: thing.c" in a Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I have a Makefile with the line:

```
thing.o: thing.c
```

I want to give an explicit command to do the same, as I need to make a modification to what is run.

What is the implied command?

If I try:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) thing.c -o thing.o
```

I get an error, so I assume that this is not what is implicit.

When I use the implicit make rule (i.e. I specify no command) it works properly.

(The error, only when explicitly specifying the command, is:

```
/opt/avr8-gnu-toolchain-linux_x86_64/bin/avr-gcc -g -Wall -mcall-prologues -mmcu=atmega328p  -Os thing.o -Wl,-gc-sections -Wl,-relax -o pmu.obj
pmu.o: In function `__vector_22':
(.text+0x7c): multiple definition of `__bad_interrupt'
/opt/avr8-gnu-toolchain-linux_x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5/crtatmega328p.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/opt/avr8-gnu-toolchain-linux_x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/../../../../avr/bin/ld: Disabling relaxation: it will not work with multiple definitions
thing.o: In function `__vectors':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vectors'
/opt/avr8-gnu-toolchain-linux_x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5/crtatmega328p.o:(.vectors+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [thing.obj] Error 1
```

but the exact error is unimportant - I need to find what I can replace the implicit command with.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does just compile (not link), thus you need option -c:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c thing.c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `make -pn` to dump the built-in rules, the one you're looking for is

```
%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

which can be further broken down into

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c -o $@ $<
```

`-c` is probably the main culprit although `CPPFLAGS` could play a role too.